# Error while running spring boot tests, SpringRunner.class Not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, junit5, spring-test-mvc, springrunner

When I try to invoke JUnit test cases from my Spring Boot Application, I am getting following error:

I am using this annotation in my Test class.

> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

[image]

After I add JUnit library from project dependencies, it gives me following error:

[image]

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner not present
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:349)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my gradle dependencies:
[image]

Also, I have the affected class in the class path:
[image]

My spring boot version is 2.0.4. Editor is SpringToolSuite. Could someone please help me resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running Junit by creating another sample project with Gradle and it just works fine and got surprised to see that below are the two dependencies creating issues mentioned in my post. It just works fine if I remove those dependencies. Not sure what's happening here:

**compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:2.9.6')**

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your sample project or at least provide the entire `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I have added screenshot of my gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pull in the JUnit 4 dependency via Eclipse's "JUnit library".

Instead, you should use the version of JUnit 4 that the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency pulls in *transitively* (and automatically). That should pull in JUnit 4.12 for you, which is required by all modern versions of Spring Boot Test.

If that doesn't help you sort out the problem, please post your entire Gradle build script (or as much as you can share).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, I read the same in the spring documentation and was expecting it to work without adding it explicitly. However, I tried as mentioned in my post just to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the dependency of JUnit because it's like spring is trying to find something in the org/junit/ but you didn't have that.

I never use gradle but for maven it should be like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not help even after adding junit dependency in gradle: 
  **testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')**

Comment: Can you expand all of your dependency for me please. I want to see the version of each jar file that you need. Maybe this error can be caused by version conflict of some dependency.

Comment: I have added screenshot of my gradle dependencies

Comment: From you answer, first thing, you don't need `jackson.core` and `hibernate-validator` in your gradle dependencies because they are already included in `spring-boot-starter-web`. And also sorry for the wrong information, the `junit` is also included in `spring-boot-starter-test` and make sure you are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version 2.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

@trjade, here is the screenshot of my dependencies:

[image]